# prepare for calling ParseAST. Fatal error

Tags: c++, parsing, compiler-construction, clang

I'm reading the book `Getting Started with LLVM Core Libraries` and trying to implement an example from page 100 `Chapter 4: Frontend`. But got an error on the last line of code `clang::ParseAST(CI.getSema());`:

```
[bash@bash book]$ ./book_clang test.c 
fatal error: error opening file '<invalid loc>':
```

What should I add to prepare for `ParseAST`?

code:

```
#include "llvm/ADT/IntrusiveRefCntPtr.h"
#include "llvm/Support/CommandLine.h"

#include "clang/Basic/Diagnostic.h"

#include "clang/Frontend/CompilerInstance.h"

#include "clang/Basic/TargetInfo.h"
#include "clang/Basic/TargetOptions.h"

#include "llvm/Support/Host.h"
#include <memory>
#include <string>

#include "clang/Basic/FileManager.h"
#include "clang/Basic/SourceManager.h"
#include "clang/Lex/PreprocessorOptions.h"
#include "clang/Lex/Preprocessor.h"

#include "clang/AST/ASTConsumer.h"
#include "clang/Frontend/ASTConsumers.h"

#include "llvm/Support/raw_ostream.h"

#include "clang/Parse/ParseAST.h"

#include "clang/AST/ASTContext.h"


static llvm::cl::opt<std::string> fileName(llvm::cl::Positional, llvm::cl::desc("Input file"), llvm::cl::Required);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    llvm::cl::ParseCommandLineOptions(argc, argv, "My simple front end\n");
    clang::CompilerInstance CI;
    clang::DiagnosticOptions diagnosticOptions;
    CI.createDiagnostics();

    std::shared_ptr<clang::TargetOptions> PTO = std::make_shared<clang::TargetOptions>();
    PTO->Triple = llvm::sys::getDefaultTargetTriple();
    clang::TargetInfo *PTI = clang::TargetInfo::CreateTargetInfo(CI.getDiagnostics(), PTO);
    CI.setTarget(PTI);

    CI.createFileManager();//References getFileSystemOpts(), clang::vfs::getRealFileSystem(), hasVirtualFileSystem(), and setVirtualFileSystem().
    CI.createSourceManager( CI.getFileManager());//References getDiagnostics().
    CI.createPreprocessor(clang::TU_Complete);
    CI.getPreprocessorOpts().UsePredefines = false;

    std::unique_ptr< clang::ASTConsumer > astConsumer = clang::CreateASTPrinter(NULL, "");
    CI.setASTConsumer(std::move(astConsumer));

    CI.createASTContext();
    CI.createSema(clang::TU_Complete, NULL);//after getASTConsumer(), getASTContext(), and getPreprocessor().
    const clang::FileEntry *file =    CI.getFileManager().getFile(fileName);
    if (!file) {
        llvm::errs() << "File not found: " << fileName;
        return 1;
    }
    CI.getSourceManager().createFileID(file, clang::SourceLocation(), clang::SrcMgr::C_User);


    CI.getDiagnosticClient().BeginSourceFile(CI.getLangOpts(), 0);
    clang::ParseAST(CI.getSema());
    // Print AST statistics
//   CI.getASTContext().PrintStats();
//  CI.getASTContext().Idents.PrintStats();

    return 0;
}
```

for executable need to pass c-file, for example:
**test.c**

```
int main() {
char *msg = "Hello, world!\n";
write(1, msg, 14);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the problem is solved. Need to set `MainFileID` for `CompilerInstence`'s `SourceManager`

```
clang::FileID mainFileID = CI.getSourceManager().createFileID(file,    clang::SourceLocation(), clang::SrcMgr::C_User);
CI.getSourceManager().setMainFileID(mainFileID);
```

The problem was that `clang::ParseAST` calls (`S` is `Sema`)   `S.getPreprocessor().EnterMainSourceFile();` that calls `SourceMgr.getMainFileID();`

```
void Preprocessor::EnterMainSourceFile() {
assert(NumEnteredSourceFiles == 0 && "Cannot reenter the main file!");
FileID MainFileID = SourceMgr.getMainFileID();
```

But `MainFileID` was'n set

**corrected full code is:**

```
#include "llvm/Support/CommandLine.h"

#include "clang/Basic/Diagnostic.h"

#include "clang/Frontend/CompilerInstance.h"

#include "clang/Basic/TargetInfo.h"
#include "clang/Basic/TargetOptions.h"

#include "llvm/Support/Host.h"
#include <memory>
#include <string>

#include "clang/Basic/FileManager.h"
#include "clang/Basic/SourceManager.h"
#include "clang/Lex/PreprocessorOptions.h"
#include "clang/Lex/Preprocessor.h"

#include "clang/AST/ASTConsumer.h"
#include "clang/Frontend/ASTConsumers.h"

#include "llvm/Support/raw_ostream.h"

#include "clang/Parse/ParseAST.h"

#include "clang/AST/ASTContext.h"


static llvm::cl::opt<std::string> fileName(llvm::cl::Positional, llvm::cl::desc("Input file"), llvm::cl::Required);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{      
    llvm::cl::ParseCommandLineOptions(argc, argv, "My simple front end\n");

    clang::CompilerInstance CI;
    clang::DiagnosticOptions diagnosticOptions;
    CI.createDiagnostics();

    std::shared_ptr<clang::TargetOptions> PTO = std::make_shared<clang::TargetOptions>();
    PTO->Triple = llvm::sys::getDefaultTargetTriple();
    clang::TargetInfo *PTI = clang::TargetInfo::CreateTargetInfo(CI.getDiagnostics(), PTO);
    CI.setTarget(PTI);

    CI.createFileManager();//References getFileSystemOpts(), clang::vfs::getRealFileSystem(), hasVirtualFileSystem(), and setVirtualFileSystem().
    CI.createSourceManager( CI.getFileManager());//References getDiagnostics().
    CI.createPreprocessor(clang::TU_Complete);
    CI.getPreprocessorOpts().UsePredefines = false;

    std::unique_ptr< clang::ASTConsumer > astConsumer = clang::CreateASTPrinter(NULL, "");
    CI.setASTConsumer(std::move(astConsumer));

    CI.createASTContext();
    CI.createSema(clang::TU_Complete, NULL);//after getASTConsumer(), getASTContext(), and getPreprocessor().
    const clang::FileEntry *file = CI.getFileManager().getFile(fileName);
    if (!file) {
            llvm::errs() << "File not found: " << fileName;
            return 1;
    }
    clang::FileID mainFileID = CI.getSourceManager().createFileID(file, clang::SourceLocation(), clang::SrcMgr::C_User);
    CI.getSourceManager().setMainFileID(mainFileID);


    CI.getDiagnosticClient().BeginSourceFile(CI.getLangOpts(), 0);
    clang::ParseAST(CI.getSema());
    // Print AST statistics
    CI.getASTContext().PrintStats();
    CI.getASTContext().Idents.PrintStats();

    return 0;
}
```